# Site só carrega na extensão Live Server

Tags: html, css

tá rolando uma parada bizarra comigo, meu site só identifica o CSS e o JS se for carregado pela extensão Live Server, se eu tentar abrir direto pelo index.html, o navegador não reconhece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu código HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/owl/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/owl/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/icona.png">
    <title>Cultflix</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container"> <!-- Container Principal da Parte Superior da Página -->
            <div class="logo-cultflix">
            <img src="/img/logo-cultflix.png" id="home" alt="Cultflix" srcset="">
            </div> <!-- Logo Cultflix -->
            <nav> <!-- Menu de Navegação -->
                <a href="#" class="btn-active">Início</a>
                <a href="#titulo" class="btn">Filmes</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Séries</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Documentários</a>
            </nav>
            <div class="barra-de-pesquisa"> <!-- Barra de Pesquisa -->
                <input type="text" name="searchbar" placeholder="Pesquise títulos...">
                <input id="btn-search" type="submit" name="searchbutton" style="display: none;">
                <label for="btn-search">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </label>
              </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main> <!-- Conteúdo Principal da Página -->
        <div class="filme-principal"> 
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo-descricao">
                <div class="logo-filme-principal">
                <img src="img/logo-filme-principal.png" class="logo" alt="Blade Runner 2049">    
                </div>
                    <p class="dados-filme-principal">Ano de Lançamento: 2017</p>
                    <p class="descricao-filme-principal">Decorridos trinta anos após o filme original, a trama acompanha os passos de K, um replicante que trabalha como blade runner para a polícia de Los Angeles.
                    </p>
                </div>
                    <div class="botoes">
                        <button role="button" class="botao">
                            <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
                            Assistir
                        </button>
                        <button role="button" class="botao2">
                            Mais informações
                        </button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <section>
    <!-- CARROSEL 1 -->
    <div class="carrosel-filmes">
        <h2 id="titulo">Clássicos Imperdíveis</h2>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme1.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme2.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme3.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme6.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme5.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme4.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme7.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme8.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CARROSEL 2 -->
    <div class="carrosel-filmes">
        <h2 class="titulo2">Coming of Age</h2>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme18.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme20.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme19.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme17.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme3.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme6.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme2.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="filme">
                <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme1.webp" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- CARROSEL 3 -->
        <div class="carrosel-filmes">
            <h2 class="titulo2">Post-Horror A24</h2>
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme15.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme14.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme8.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme16.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme3.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme6.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme2.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme1.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <!-- CARROSEL 4 -->
        <div class="carrosel-filmes">
            <h2 class="titulo2">Cultura Pop</h2>
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme21.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme22.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme12.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme4.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme3.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme6.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme2.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div class="filme">
                    <img class="box-filme" src="/img/filme1.webp" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
        <a class="topo" href="#home"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
    </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb4d127565.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? :(

Comment: Já tentou tirar essa `/` do início do caminho dos arquivos no src ?

Answer (score 2):

Retire essa barra no inicio do endereço de seus CSS e eles carregarão normalmente. -- href: "style/main.css"; O live server pode corrigir alguns erros. Mas se no browser apresentar erro, abra o console do navegador, geralmente o erro é apresentado lá para te ajudar a solucionar mais rápido.